# Comment traduire « sandbox » et ses dérivés (« sandboxed », « sandboxing »…) dans un contexte informatique ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique

Je cherche à traduire le terme *sandbox* et surtout ses dérivés comme *sandboxed* ou *sandboxing* (dans un contexte informatique, voir la [page Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9_informatique)) par exemple).

Le terme retenu pour *sandbox* dans ce contexte est apparemment « bac à sable » (traduction directe du terme de langage courant), par exemple dans le [grand dictionnaire terminologique de l’OQLF](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26520079). Mais je vois mal comment le dériver pour traduire *sandboxed* ou *sandboxing*.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à garder les termes anglais... Même la page Wikipedia le fait

Comment: Donc par exemple, la phrase “A sandboxed version is available.” deviendrait « Une version sandboxed est disponible. » ? Bof…

Comment: Une version sandbox/avec sandbox ? (L'idéal serait de rajouter 2-3 phrases que tu veux traduire, une pour chaque mot, histoire de voir le contexte ; surtout pour sandboxing en fait)

Comment: Généralement on garde le mot de base pour le dériver à la française : "une version sandboxée", mais j'imagine qu'il n'y a pas de règle officielle. Même si dans ce cas-là je dirais juste "une version sandbox", même en anglais d'ailleurs. Ou du coup, "une version bac-à-sable". Je ne comprends pas l'intérêt d'utiliser le participe passé dans cette phrase précise.

Comment: Pour _sandboxed_, la phrase est : “A sandboxed version of <thisapp> is available as <thisapp_sandboxed>.”. Pour _sandboxing_, je n’ai pas de cas à disposition (je demande par prévention et tant qu’à faire au passage), mais par exemple cette page du wiki de Mozilla regorge d’exemple (ainsi que pour _sandboxed_ d’ailleurs) : https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox.

Comment: Du coup les deux seules possibilités que je vois sont "sandboxer" et "mettre en bac à sable" pour "sandboxing". Pour "sandboxed", je dirai "sandboxé(e)", "(avec) sandbox" ou "avec bac à sable".

Comment: Pourquoi pas pas _isoler_? On peut laisser tomber l'idée de bac à sable dans ce cas, en faveur _d'isolation_, qui me semble plus naturel et suffisamment proche.

Comment: Pas forcément faux, mais il me semble que l'on utilise généralement sandbox/bac à sable

Comment: Je crois qu'il y a une nuance réelle entre _sandbox_ en général, et _sandboxed/sandboxing_. _Sandbox_ peut faire référence à un _environnement de test_ (test drive...), mais _sandboxed/sandboxing_ fait plutôt référence à une notion _d'isolation_ pour raisons de sécurité.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Bac à sable » est couramment employé en informatique.

Cette métaphore, en anglais comme en français, contient plus que l'aspect isolation / cloisonnement. Il y a aussi, comme dans les vrais bacs à sable, une notion importante de sécurité. Dans un bac à sable, il n'y a pas de risque de casse, ou plus précisément, les incidents qu'y peuvent s'y produire n'ont pas de conséquences préjudiciables. On peut dont se permettre d'y « jouer » sans risque, sans que cela n'ait de conséquences fâcheuses à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur.

Je recommande donc de conserver cette expression et l'on peut très bien traduire *sandboxed* par « (mis) en bac à sable » et *sandboxing* par « mise/mettre en bac à sable ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54177/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-comment-traduire-sandbox-et-ses-derives-).

Answer (score 0):

*Sandbox*, *sandboxing* et *sandboxed* sont des termes apparentés, mais qui recouvrent des nuances distinctes selon le contexte dans lequel le mot est employé en informatique, ce que la traduction directe et "fourre-tout" *bac à sable* en français ne distingue pas forcément bien. Les trois termes reposent en partie sur l'idée de *séparation* ou *d'isolation* d'un programme client par rapport à son hôte, ce qui permet au programme client de ne pas avoir d'impact sur le fonctionnement de l'hôte. Sur le plan technique, les resources du client et de l'hôte sont séparées. Mais une autre dimension est celle de *jeu*, *d'essai* comme on va le voir.

Examinons d'abord le mot *sandbox*. [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/testdrive/) utilise par exemple:

> AWS Test Drive provides a private IT **sandbox** environment containing preconfigured server based solutions. In under an hour, and using a step-by-step lab manual and video, launch, login and learn about these popular 3rd party IT solutions, powered by AWS and CloudFormation.

Ici, *sandbox* a le sens d'un espace confiné, un environnement de test dans lequel on peut "jouer" avec AWS sans conséquences néfastes, comme l'enfant qui joue dans un bac à sable. On peut jouer dans la *sandbox* sans se faire mal, sans catastrophe pour soi ni personne d'autre. La traduction *bac à sable*, avec sa dimension ludique, est particulièrement appropriée dans ce cas.

Cependant, voici un exemple pour le mot *sandboxed* (du projet [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/Sandbox-FAQ)), ou le sens est proche, mais avec une nuance différente:

> What is the **sandbox**?
>
> The **sandbox** is a C++ library that allows the creation of ***sandboxed*** processes — processes that execute within a very restrictive environment. The only resources ***sandboxed*** processes can freely use are CPU cycles and memory. For example, sandboxes processes cannot write to disk or display their own windows. What exactly they can do is controlled by an explicit policy. Chromium renderers are ***sandboxed*** processes.
>
> What does and doesn't it protect against?
>
> *The sandbox limits the severity of bugs in code running inside the sandbox. Such bugs cannot install persistent malware in the user's account (because writing to the filesystem is banned). Such bugs also cannot read and steal arbitrary files from the user's machine.*

Dans l'exemple AWS, *sandbox* a une nuance de test, d'essai, on va dans la *sandbox* pour essayer quelque chose de façon éphémère, mais dans le cas de Chromium, il n'y a rien d'éphémère, il ne s'agit pas d'un *Test Drive*, d'essayer quelque chose, mais bien d'un *mode d'opération continu et normal* *en sandbox*, dont le but est la *sécurité* par *séparation* et *isolation*. Dans ce cas, la traduction *bac à sable* est encore utilisable/utilisée, mais la nuance ludique de l'enfant qui joue n'y est plus, et la nuance d'isolation devient plus importante.

Il y a donc bien deux nuances de sens pour les mots [*sandbox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) et [*sandboxing/sandboxed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) en anglais, la première nuance faisant plutôt référence à un environnement de test, la deuxième nuance étant propre au domaine de la sécurité. Voir aussi, par exemple, ce [lien](http://techgenix.com/better-security-through-sandboxing/), ou [celui-ci](http://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/application-sandboxing).

Cette deuxième nuance, celle de *sandboxing/sandboxed*, peut aussi être rapprochée d'outils tels que [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), dont le domaine est *application containerization*. On trouve [aussi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)): *Virtual machines emulate a complete host computer, on which a conventional operating system may boot and run as on actual hardware. The guest operating system runs **sandboxed** in the sense that it does not function natively on the host and can only access host resources through the emulator.* ce qui permet de comprendre une machine virtuelle comme une forme de *sandbox*. Encore une fois, dans ce contexte, l'idée de l'enfant qui joue innocemment et sans conséquences devient plus lointaine. Il peut y avoir catastrophe pour le client dans la *sandbox*, mais sans répercussion globale pour le système hôte.

Au vu de ces nuances, on pourrait proposer d'autres traductions que *bac à sable*: *environnement de test*, *environnement d'essai*, mais aussi: *container d'isolation*, *exécution isolée*, *exécution séparée* ... toutes ces nuances pouvant être couvertes par le mot anglais suivant le contexte.